# Attempted to add an ID already in GraphQLSegment

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

My Relay/GraphQL fragment contains two different queries, both of which return objects of the same type, and there is often some overlap between the result sets returned by either (and that's perfectly fine with me). I see the following warnings in the browser:

```
Attempted to add an ID already in GraphQLSegment: client:client:15254944391:UmV2aWV3ZXI6MQ==
cra.dll.js:106483 Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment: 52 to (0, 2)
cra.dll.js:106483 Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment: 53 to (0, 2)
cra.dll.js:106483 Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment: 54 to (0, 2)
cra.dll.js:106483 Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment: 55 to (0, 2)
```

Can someone confirm that this is indeed due to me seeing the same Relay object twice? How do I silence the warning or at least debug it further?

Comment: Could you meanwhile find a fix for this? I am getting the same warning when trying to get details of my entities of type called `User` which have each a list of `Role` defined (n to n relation). It seems that loading a `Role` two times (visiting two `Users` with same assigned role) triggers this warning.

Comment: @MichaelHilus, nothing yet, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can tell with out looking at the code but you might be running your nodeDefinition on your type 2x. If you defined the globalIDField on your top level object, like so:

```
let {nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(
(globalId) => {
  let { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId)
  console.log('NodeDefinitions (globalId), id:', id)
  console.log('NodeDefinitions (globalId), type:', type)

  if (type === 'TopLevelObject') {
    return toplevelobject
  }
  return null
},
(obj) => {
  if (obj instanceof TopLevelObject) {
    return toplevelobjectType 
  } 
  return null 
}
```

)

Then you should refer to any other objects like this:

let itemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Item',
    fields: () => ({
      id: fromGlobalId('Item', obj => obj._id),
      // OR, not both..
      id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
        resolve: (obj) => obj._id
      },
      name: { type: GraphQLString },
      url: { type: GraphQLString },
      state: { type: GraphQLString },
      likesCount: { type: GraphQLInt },
      createdAt: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: ...
      }
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface]
  })

Either seems to work. If you want to share your code, happy to look at it.